# Check if cell from the same row but different column isn't empty

Tags: vba, excel

So I have small script in Excel that goes through the column and checks the cell value, then it checks a cell in the same row but different column. 
For example: I go through C column and if C8 isn't empty then I check if A8 is empty. But I don't know how to check cells from the same row. Here's my code:

```
For Each xdata In range_data

If IsEmpty(xdata.Value) = False Then

    If IsEmpty(???????.Value) = True Then
        ......

    ElseIf IsEmpty(???????.Value) = False Then
        .....

    End If

End If

Next xdata
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that xData is a Range variable, you have a couple of options. You can use:

```
If IsEmpty(Cells(xData.row, 1)
```

...where the `1` is the column you want to check. You can also use:

```
If IsEmpty(xData.Offset(0,-2))
```

...where the `-2` is the number of columns to count to the left of the xData column to get to the value you want to check. Finally, you can use:

```
If IsEmpty(Range("A" & xData.row))
```

...where `"A"` is the letter of the column you want to check. Each method has its advantages and disadvantages - the `Cells` method allows you to use column numbers instead of letters but is a little harder to read, the `Offset` method allows you to use numbers again but if you change the column of xData and forget to change the offset value it can cause errors, and the `Range` method is easier to read but does require that hard-coded letter value.

Answer (score 2):

There are many ways....here is one:

```
Sub Silva()
    Dim range_data As Range, xdata As Range
    Set range_data = Range("C1:C10")

    For Each xdata In range_data
        v = xdata.Value
        If v <> "" Then
            If xdata.offfset(0, -2).Value <> "" Then
                'do something
            Else
                'do something else
            End If
        End If
    Next xdata
End Sub
```

Comment: why do you need the `v` ? wouldn't `If xdata.Value <> "" Then` result the same ?